# Javascript hide and display elements by id not working for multiple cases

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, var, addeventlistener

i don't really know any javascript but I've been able to piece together a means to programmatically hide html tables on a webpage using versions of the following line to hide them when the page opens:

```
document.getElementById("approved").style.display = "none";
```

etc

and then depending on a value being chosen from a select menu have the element appear, using this:

```js
document.getElementById('cboaim').addEventListener('change', function (){
var style = this.value == "10" ? 'block' : 'none';
document.getElementById('approved').style.display = style;
var style = this.value == "13" ? 'block' : 'none';
document.getElementById('enddate').style.display = style;
var style = this.value == "14" ? 'block' : 'none';
document.getElementById('tortm').style.display = style;
var style = this.value == "17" ? 'block' : 'none';
document.getElementById('enddate').style.display = style;
});
```

Which works for virtually everything except for the two lines relating to 'enddate'.  It works for ONE of the values but not the other.  I'm assuming referring to the element id twice breaks this code (both select 13 and 17 need this date box to appear).

For more complex reasons I can't just add another table with a different id so I'm hoping somebody out there knows an easy way around the problem.  Please be gentle with me, I know the javascript is probably offensive to a programmer ;-)

I'd also happily use a function attached to an onchange on the select if that was easier? I'm only using the addeventlistener because a search on stackoverflow came up with that particular solution.

Cheers
Les

Comment: What enddate is? `div`, `input`?

Comment: are you saying your HTML has two elements with the same ID?

Comment: You can't have 2 elements with the same id's

Comment: What you can do is give on a different id or give them the same class and access them that way...

Comment: @Les, is `'enddate'` one element that has to be displayed depending on 2 possible values?

Comment: @marianoc84 - enddate is indeed an input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all those var statements. Declaring the same var in the same scope multiple times is invalid JS.

Now, the check for value `"17"` will always override that for `"13"`, change the condition on the `'enddate'` element:

```
document.getElementById('cboaim').addEventListener('change', function (){
    document.getElementById('approved').style.display = 
        this.value == "10" ? 'block' : 'none';

    document.getElementById('tortm').style.display = 
        this.value == "14" ? 'block' : 'none';

    document.getElementById('enddate').style.display = 
        (this.value == "13" || this.value == "17") ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

This will set `'enddate'` to display if the value is `"13"` *or* if the value is `"17"`.

Comment: Technically, no. However, most IDEs will throw a warning.

Comment: oops, do I comment here .. Guys.. that did it! Thank you both for not only solving it, but damned fast too! Sorry I wasn't clear about the OR. I can't recall where I found the original code with all the variables repeated, but was just happy the eventlistener worked (or it did until I complicated matters with the multiple operators) @Dan300

Comment: You could, but I've read the other message, too. You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You cannot have two elements with the same id because an id is meant to be an unique identifier. You **must** find a way to give the tables separate ids.</strike>

If you wanted to do something like this you could give them the same name (or class) instead and do something like this:

```
var style = this.value == "13" ? 'block' : 'none';
document.getElementsByName('enddate')[0].style.display = style; //First enddate element
style = this.value == "17" ? 'block' : 'none';
document.getElementsByName('enddate')[1].style.display = style; //Second enddate element
```

Also, every time you write `var style = ...` you are defining a new variable. Similar thing to above, variables should not really have the same name. So you should give them different names or remove the `var` keyword from all but the first one.

**EDIT:**

I have just realised that the question is not as clear as I thought: You might mean that if 13 or 17 are selected from the menu, the style is not always applied to the single element?

In this case, you need an if statement to decide if 13 OR 17 were selected, and apply the correct style. For example:

```
if((this.value == "17")||(this.value == "13")) {
  document.getElementById('enddate').style.display = "block";
} else {
  document.getElementById('enddate').style.display = "none";
}
```

The problem with your code is that the check for 17 was done separately and after the check for 13, overwriting that style. Therefore nothing happened when 13 was selected.

Comment: @Cerbrus Ah yes, this was because I added the second paragraph after the rest, so I forgot to take out the `var`! Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: From the question: _"both select 13 and 17 need this date box to appear"_ I suspect `'enddate'` is _one_ element, that has to show for `13` _or_ `17`.

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah, just figured that out :)

Comment: Guys.. that did it!  Thank you both for not only solving it, but damned fast too!  Sorry I wasn't clear about the OR.  I can't recall where I found the original code with all the variables repeated, but was just happy the eventlistener worked (or it did until I complicated matters with the multiple operators)